# Covariance issue with firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Since cloud_firestore 2.0.0 we must now [add generics <Map<String, dynamic>> to our doc references ect](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration/).

**Now I get these runtime errors when I am using firstWhere:**
_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type '() => QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>

I semi understand the problem, it seems that the orElse Callback expects a return type of type QueryDocumentSnapshot but at runtime, the docs argument is of type _JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot.

Can someone shine some light on why this is the case and how to solve this?

```
List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> createExploreDocList(
    List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> docs, int length) {


  final QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> basicDoc = docs.firstWhere(
    (element) => !element.data()["requires_plus"],
    orElse: () => docs.first 
  );
}
```

Related: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33841

Comment: How have you solved this? I'm having a similar issue with firstWhere on a List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, solved it like this:

```
  final QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> basicDoc = docs.firstWhere(
    (element) => !element.data()["requires_plus"],
    orElse: () => null 
  ) ?? docs.first;
```